# Is there debug/release mode for Python in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm used to debug/release modes for C++. When I press `Ctrl+F5` (Run without debugging) to run my Python script in VS Code, I see in the terminal:

```
(.pick) paul@desktop:~/upwork/pick/code$  cd /home/paul/upwork/pick/code ; /usr/bin/env /home/paul/upwork/pick/code/.pick/bin/python /home/paul/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 37183 -- /
```

Why the `python/debugpy/launcher` when I chose *Run without debugging*? It suggests debugging mode. Is there is such thing as debug/release mode for Python scripts in VS Code?

**EDIT**

I want to make sure there is no debugging related overhead when I run my script in VS Code.

Comment: Are you just trying to run a Python script? Does [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_run-python-code) help? I think it would be helpful to clarify what exactly you’re trying to accomplish.

Comment: With C++ the obj files are built with debugging information. In Python there's no difference in the compiled pyc file, the bitecode is identical. It's just the interpreter which runs with debugging options.

Comment: There is, it’s the `-O` switch. It disables assertions and sets `__debug__` to False. VSCode failing to use it is their problem.

Comment: @PeterWood There must be some overhead when running the interpreter with debugging options, right?

Comment: @JBallin I want to make sure there is no debugging overhead when I run my script in VS Code.

Comment: @PaulJurczak, "running the interpreter with debugging options" -- _what_ debugging options? The really heavy stuff like `-m trace` is off by default even in development phase. The equivalent to debug symbols in C/C++ -- tracking names/line numbers/etc at runtime -- is _always_ on in Python, even in release mode, unless you use obfuscation tools (and those don't make it faster to run; they just make it harder to reproduce the original source code).

Comment: @PaulJurczak, ...while `-O` and `-OO` exist, the gains from them are so tiny as to be effectively nonexistent, and they break tools that do runtime introspection of docstrings. If you care so much about performance as to need the benefit of `-O`, you should be using a higher-performance language, not Python. (Might I suggest [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/) as something with a similar level of user friendliness, but vastly better performance?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do care about performance and use C++ for that. I just wanted to know what is the Python debug/release story, since that topic is very sparsely covered.

Comment: I think we've answered it's "sparse" because there's not really anything to cover

Comment: Exactly. If VS Code were designed for Python it wouldn't have the debug/release distinction at all. It's an artifact of which languages the IDE you're using was designed for, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

For scripts, there is not.

Python is interpreted. It is not compiled with debug markers, so there is no need to remove them for a "release mode".

Regarding VSCode, refer [Python - Configure and run the debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger)

Comment: Yes, but there must be some overhead when running the interpreter with debugging options, right?

Comment: @PaulJurczak, no. Don't think of "debugging options" as a vague concept -- break it down into exactly what you think is going to take the time. Python _always_ tracks symbolic names for stack frames / variables / etc.; it's not something that can be turned off. So you only get overhead when you start doing things that are truly extra: Setting verbose log levels, or enabling statement-level tracing or profiling. And those truly extra things are off by default even in most development environments.

Comment: @PaulJurczak, ...another thing that can add performance impact when you're compiled as a dev build in C/C++ is if you have hooks in compiler-generated code to do things like increment performance counters or notate stack frames with information for the debugger, but Python _has no compiler-generated code in the first place_. You can't add extra hooks in compiler-generated code if you don't have a compiler -- and everything needed for the standard tracing tools &c to work is included in the regular AST and bytecode, because Python offers the same metaprogramming semantics full-time.

Comment: (...which is why, unlike in C where you can only get a proper stack trace when you compiled as a dev build, in Python you _always_ get proper stack traces; the overhead is always there, 100% of the time, and so are the things you pay that overhead to get).